# Swift 4 JSON Decode [String: Any]

Tags: json, swift, codable

I'm in a situation where the response JSON is of kind [String: Any], something like below:

> { "response": {"a": 1, "b": "String", "c": [] }}

Now at the client side, we don't know the keys for the response, we need to consume the response as it is and forward the dictionary received as a response to another api. Hence, the requirement is to store the response as [String: Any]. With the code below to parse the response,

```
try values.decode([String: Any].self, forKey: "response")
```

I get an error

> No 'decode' candidates produce the expected contextual result type
>   '[String : Any]'.

Please suggest on how I can parse it as [String: Any].

Thank you

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50030133/2857130

Comment: If you don't know the keys don't use `Decodable`, use traditional `JSONSerialization`. The goal of `Decodable` is to get structs or classes from the JSON.

Comment: I don't know the keys for one value, others I know. So, is there a hybrid approach?

Comment: This article helped.
https://medium.com/grand-parade/parsing-fields-in-codable-structs-that-can-be-of-any-json-type-e0283d5edb

Comment: With this spaghetti-code in the article you are going to lose the advantage (and efficiency) of `Codable`.

Comment: @vadian, can you be more elaborate on the statement?